# What can cause a blue screen while running .py script?

Tags: windows-7, python, bsod

I am writing a code for logistic regression that actually seems to work, but, for some parameter values, it causes the blue screen (it's instanteneous, so I cannot read there anything about the cause of it).

**How do I determine what causes the problem?** Are there any tools that would actually indicate if there is some faulty hardware, or if the problem is in something else? Can if be influenced by the fact that the dataset is pretty big (however, I am not sure if 100x3198 array is THAT big)?

Only few times during 3 years I had some hardware issues with my PC, so I am not sure if now something is actually wrong with it.

Not sure how important this is, but here's code and dataset (only first 100 rows are used): https://github.com/iegorval/neural_nets, https://www.kaggle.com/keplersmachines/kepler-labelled-time-series-data.

Comment: For simplicity, upload a minidump to http://www.osronline.com/page.cfm?name=Analyze.  What does it say?  You should have them under \windows\minidump\

Comment: What if I don't have a new minidump file? According to the settings, it should create a minidump file on memory dump, but the last one I have is about 2-3 months old. I had my system crashed around 5-6 times over these 2 days, but no minidumps were generated (all the minidumps from previous crashes seem to be there).

Comment: What's the BSOD cause? You can also get more info using [Blue Screen View.](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html)